# How to read data from .sql file in Cypress?

Tags: sql, database, cypress

I have a few .sql files which contain the SQL commands to GET data from my app-db.

I am using Cypress to automate reading data from DB and passing that as an array for example an array of ids to an API which in turn would use the id to fetch me a response.

So far, I have been able to connect to the dB and execute a code when it is hardcoded into the automation script.

The next step for me is to create a few utility functions which would read the query from a .sql file based on the API that needs to be called.

What I have done is :

`In /plugins/index.js`

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connections = {
     dbSource : {
         host: <myHostIP>,
         port: <myPort>,
         user: <myUserName>,
         password: <myPassword>,
         database: <myDbName>
     }
}

function queryDB(connectionInfo, query) {
    const connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionInfo);

    connection.connect();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
             if (error) {
                 return reject(error);
             }

             connection.end();

             return resolve(results);
         })
    })
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('task', {
       queryDatabase({ dbName, query }) {
            const connectionInfo = connections[dbName];

            if (!connectionInfo) {
                 throw new Error(`Do not have DB connection under name ${dbName}`);
       }

       return queryDB(connectionInfo, query);
    },

})
```

`In /integration/test-code.js`

```
import getQuery from "../query-generator/get-query";

const dbName = 'myDbName';

describe('Connect and fetch data from myDb', () => {
    
    it('Fetches all data from my_table table in myDb', () => {
        
        var query = getQuery.queryToFetchDataFromMyDb();
        cy.log(query);
        cy.task('queryDatabase', { dbName, query }).then((res) => {
            expect(res).to.have.lengthOf(1);
        });
        
    });
    
})
```

`In /query-generator/get-query.js`

```
class getQuery {
    static queryToFetchDataFromMyDb()() {
        cy.readFile('My Queries.sql').then((queryString) => {
            return queryString;
        });
    }
}

export default getQuery;
```

However, I am getting an error when I run this code, which says:

```
task
queryDatabase, {dbname: amsQANew, query: undefined}

**CypressError**

cy.task('queryDatabase') failed with the following error:

> ER_EMPTY_QUERY: Query was empty
```

Am I reading the file wrong? How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in `getQuery()`,

```js
class getQuery {
  static queryToFetchDataFromMyDb()() {
    return cy.readFile('My Queries.sql')  // .then() does nothing here
  }
}
```

The readFile is asynchronous, so in the test

```js
getQuery.queryToFetchDataFromMyDb().then(query => {
  cy.log(query);
  cy.task('queryDatabase', { dbName, query }).then((res) => {
    ...
  });
})
```

The `getQuery` class clutters up the logic, you would figure it out more easily by just using the Cypress commands directly in the test

```js
cy.readFile('My Queries.sql').then(query => {
  cy.log(query);
  cy.task('queryDatabase', { dbName, query }).then((res) => {
    ...
  });
})
```

Comment: This was awesome!! Thanks :)